# Flutter runtime Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, dart, redux, google-cloud-firestore

When i try to get data from firestore, this exception occurs.
_TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String')
I can't find the cause of the problem. Please help.

```
class ActfMiddleWare {
      ///Fetches LocationData From Firestore and Save it in Store;
      locationIndexMiddleware() {
        return (Store<AppState> store, action, NextDispatcher next) async {
          if (action is GetLocationIndex) {
            Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> locationIndex =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('locations')
                    .doc('locationIndex')
                    .get();
    
            await locationIndex.then((docSnapshot) {
              if (docSnapshot.data() != null) {
                List temp = docSnapshot.data()!['locations'];
    
                store.dispatch(SaveLocationIndex(payload: temp));
              }
            });
          }
          next(action);
        };
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error is you casting string data in the list.**

Check your data in your DB.

Here is the fix you need to change the list to string.

```
String temp = docSnapshot.data()!['locations'];
```

Here is the full code

```
class ActfMiddleWare {
      ///Fetches LocationData From Firestore and Save it in Store;
      locationIndexMiddleware() {
        return (Store<AppState> store, action, NextDispatcher next) async {
          if (action is GetLocationIndex) {
            Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> locationIndex =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('locations')
                    .doc('locationIndex')
                    .get();
    
            await locationIndex.then((docSnapshot) {
              if (docSnapshot.data() != null) {
                String temp = docSnapshot.data()!['locations']; -->Here is the change
    
                store.dispatch(SaveLocationIndex(payload: temp));
              }
            });
          }
          next(action);
        };
      }
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  Returns the same error. Also, the map is of type <String, List>. So the incoming data is a list.

Comment: Can you please add StackTrace and the database?

Comment: My bad. I found out it was an issue while dispatching an action. Thank You.

Comment: @kjm If you feel this answer helped you then please accept the answer.
Thanks